Azure Logic App Authorization Policy set via Bicep
When creating a consumption Azure Logic App using Azure Bicep -
How do you create configure Azure Active Directory Authorization Policies and set the

Policy Name
Policy Type
Claims (Issuer, Audience and a custom claim)

From Azure Portal its under Logic App > Authorization > Add Policy:
Logic App Authorization screen
Here's my bicep file:
param name string = 'testlogicapptb'
param location string = 'Australia Southeast'

resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  properties: {
    definition: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
    }
    parameters: {}
    accessControl: {
      triggers: {
        allowedCallerIpAddresses: [
          {
            addressRange: '123.1.1.1-123.1.1.1'
          }
        ]

        //Doesn't work - just trying anything
        openAuthenticationPolicies: {
          policies: {
            name: 'test'
            type: 'AAD'
            issuer: 'https://123/'
            audience: '123'
            claim: {
              name: 'role'
              value: '123'
            }
          }
        }
    }
    }
  }
}

Here's the reference documentation but it doesn't describe how to format the policies and it just circles back around on itself.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.logic/workflows?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#bicep-resource-definition
If I search the web for anything related to OpenAuthenticationAccessPolicies I can't find anything or even know if I'm looking at the right thing.
I've tried exporting the ARM template and converting that to bicep - however the policies entered through the Portal do not come out in the export.
Even if its not bicep how do I programmatically set these up?

Is terraform suits your environment? @user27975968

I would prefer bicep to match the rest of my environment but open to it, if thats the only way to solve it.

main.bicep
@description('The name of the logic app to create.')
param logicAppName string = 'wbtestlogicapp'

@description('A test URI')
param testUri string = 'https://azure.status.microsoft/status/'

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var policyName = 'aadPolicyTest'
var frequency = 'Hour'
var interval = '1'
var type = 'recurrence'
var actionType = 'http'
var method = 'GET'

resource stg 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: location
  tags: {
    displayName: logicAppName
  }
  properties: {
    definition: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      parameters: {
        testUri: {
          type: 'string'
          defaultValue: testUri
        }
      }
      triggers: {
        recurrence: {
          type: type
          recurrence: {
            frequency: frequency
            interval: interval
          }
        }
      }
      actions: {
        actionType: {
          type: actionType
          inputs: {
            method: method
            uri: testUri
          }
        }
      }
    }
    accessControl: {
      triggers: {
        openAuthenticationPolicies:{
          policies: {
            '${policyName}': {
              type: 'AAD'
              claims: [
                {
                  name: 'iss'
                  value: 'https://sts.windows.net/2xxxxxxx-3a06-xxxxxxxxx-8a1e-xxxxxx/'
                }
                {
                  name: 'aud'
                  value: 'https://management.core.windows.net'
                }
                {
                  name: 'sub'
                  value: 'xxxxxxxxxxx-7d1e-4d9f-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

output name string = stg.name
output resourceId string = stg.id
output resourceGroupName string = resourceGroup().name
output location string = location


result


Thanks that worked - how did you know that was the correct syntax to use? I am trying to understand the fundamentals.

hi @user27975968 You can just manually create the azure logicapp with authorization policy and then using Resource Explorer in azure portal to check the resource json result. and just convert to corresponding bicep. This is a very useful method

Resource Explorer is a useful tool. try to use it.  you can find it via typing in Resource Explorer in azure portal upper search bar, then finding via resource group to locate the resources you manually created, it is in json format with details.
